# "could not find or load main class" error in windows 7 with compiled ubuntu jar

Tags: java, linux, netbeans

I have a simple Swing app compiled with netbeans 7.1.2 on a ubuntu machine which has the java version:

> java version "1.6.0_22" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10.4)
>   (6b22-1.10.4-0ubuntu1~11.04.1) OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b11,
>   mixed mode)

jar works great when i use the shell using "java -jar filename.jar" in linux but in
the windows 7 with the java version 1.7.05 i get:
"Error: could not find or load main class"

How do i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error usually shows up when you don't include the current directory (`.`) in the classpath.

If there are any external libraries that you specify when starting the program, then you probably do something like `java -jar -classpath dir/library.jar program.jar`. Instead, add `.` to the classpath: `java -jar -classpath .;dir/library.jar program.jar`

Other possibilities are:

- you didn't include a Manifest in the JAR
- in the Manifest that you did include, you didn't specify which is the main class, or you did it wrong.